# How to exchange objects between UserControlWPF and WindowsForm?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have an old WinForm that combines 2 objects, but almost all metadata of the result is lost after the combining.
To solve this I created a UserControl WPF and I am using it as an element host inside the mainwindow Form.

I would like to import these 2 objects to UC and after the user selected the metadata it should return the output to the mainwindow where the metadata and the data should be integrated.

One other problem I have is to Hide and Show the UserControl.

From the MainWindow Form:

```
private Ch FirstCh = new Ch();
private Ch SecondCh = new Ch();
        
public WinForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     elementHost1.SendToBack();
     elementHost1.Hide();
}
    
private void UserCWPFButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   elementHost1.Show();
   elementHost1.BringToFront();
   Ch ThirdCh = new Ch();
   //Would like to use the ThirdCh from UserCWPF here      
}
```

From the UserControl:

```
public partial class UserCWPF : UserControl
{
    public UserCWPF()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Would like to use FirstCh and SecondCh here
    }

    private void CloseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        //Both of these leave me with a Gray square in front of the form!

    }
}
```

So far I can only properly hide the UCwpf with .SendToBack, but I don't know how to do it within the UserCWPF.
Also, Does it make sense to use a User Control WPF in an old WinForm or it should just be another form?

Comment: As much as I prefer wpf, I'm not at all sure why you're using it here. If you have a winforms project then the obvious thing to use in it is winforms rather than wpf. Unless there is some specific aspect to your requirement means wpf is uniquely suitable. There are also some limitations to the way the elementhost works.

Comment: Please limit questions to one topic per question. It is not clear what you mean with "combining objects", not "losing metadata". What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Andy I started with windows forms, but I wasn't being able to create a "toggle/sticky" button (a button that after you click and it shows it is down). So in my research I found wpf and I everywhere I saw it, said it was better than winform.
I first did the GUI that looks exactly how I wanted and now I am suffering to implement into the winform.

Comment: It might not be technically possible to do what you want. Winforms and WPF use different technology. They're oil and water.  But wouldn't setting visibility=Hidden on the elementhost work for you?

Comment: I am sorry @JonasH, I did not know that! This is my first question.
I have a winform that uses the FirstCh and SecondCh from a list.
both have the same child objects, like:
FirstCh.name = "Rafael"
FirstCh.Job="Swimmer"
FirstCh.Money=1500
SecondCh.Name="Luli"
SecondCh.Money=1550
and so on, there are around 20.
When you created the ThirdCh it would get the ThirdCh.Money=3050, but all of these other information were lost.
My WPF has theses toggle buttons for the user to select from which of these (first, second or blank) he wants.

Comment: @Andy When I do that a gray square is left where the UC was, both Hidden and Collapsed gave me the same result.

Comment: I tend to do just wpf ( or more often web ) nowadays.  Looks like the differences in transparency are going to block any hiding here.  Assuming WPF is offering some unique benefits here and you 100% need it.  How much time would it take to refactor the parent winform to wpf?

Comment: @rquente If you want to combine properties from two objects to create a third object you will need to do the combining yourself, typically when the user press a button or makes some change. The example code does not show any of this, so it is difficult to tell what the problem is. I'm not even sure if the problem is even related to wpf/winforms or if it is some other problem. When writing questions it might be a good idea to state: a) What the actual problem is. b) What solutions you have tried. c) What the result was. d) What result you would have expected.

Comment: @rquente in addition, combining WPF and winforms is mostly used when some specific control is only available in one or the other, and no suitable equivalent control can be used. This does not seem to be the case here. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)